# How to use satisfies with generic type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have components, the components have some default values that are combined with props, for all components I wrote a single function:

```
export function getAssignProps <T extends {}>(propsMass:T[]){
    return propsMass.reduce((combinedProps, props) => {
            return {...combinedProps, ...props};
        }, {} as T)
}
```

Thanks to generic the type of the props of the component is the same on output as on input. I'd like to replace "as T" with "satisfies T" to avoid additional checks later, but I'm having trouble. Do I need to write "satifies T" inside the function or return a generic object without type and where I call it, write that? Please give me a hint

I tried writing inside the function as well, as follows:

```
export function getAssignProps <T extends {}>(propsMass:T[]){
    return propsMass.reduce((combinedProps, props) => {
            return {...combinedProps, ...props};
        }, {} satisfies T)
}
```

But an error occurs
TS1360: Type '{}' does not satisfy the expected type 'T'.   '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.

Comment: `as` does not do the same thing as `satisfies`. You need `as` in this case.

Comment: "to avoid additional checks later" Can you explain this use case?  What checks do you think `satisfies` prevents but `as` requires?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of a generic type

```
function foo<T>() {
  let t: T = {...}
  // ^! cannot create instance of generic type
}
```

You have to cast

```
function foo1<T>() {
  let t: T = {...} as any
}
function foo2<T>() {
  let t = {...} as T
}
function foo3<T>(): T {
  return {...} as any
}
```